# Selenium - assert on GoogleMaps address

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, assert

I am practicing with Selenium (in Python) and am trying to find something to assertEquals to.  I open GoogleMaps, type in a destination and I want to make sure the address listed is correct.  When I click on the address and "inspect element" this is all I see:

```
<span jstcache="754" class="widget-pane-link" jsan="7.widget-pane-link">123 Broadway Ave</span>
```

When I type this however:

```
address = self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('widget-pane-link')
self.assertEqual(address,'123 Broadway Ave')
```

It throws an error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"widget-pane-link"}
```

I am not sure what else I can assert on given those "inspect" results in Chrome.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing before `self.driver.find_element_by_class_name` ? Are you waiting for element to be loaded by Chrome ?  Maybe you should read : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: @Calumah thank you.  I'm betting that is the issue here.  I will check it out